# Factorization of singular matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm studying econometric statistics, in particular cointegration, where there are a lot of matrices. Well, reading on book, there is written "$\Pi$ is $n\times n$, singular, with $r(\Pi)=k$, so it can be written as $\alpha'\cdot\beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two $k\times n$ matrices". Is this valid only for singular matrices? Thanks

Comment: If it is non-singular then $r(\Pi)=n$ and you could write $\Pi=\alpha'\cdot \beta$ with $\alpha=I$ and $\beta=\Pi$, which are both $n\times n$. Therefore the claim is true also for non-singular, but it is not a significant claim in that case.

Comment: So you're saying that $\alpha = I$ if $\Pi$ is non-singular? And $\alpha\neq\ I$ if and only if $\Pi$ is singular?

Comment: Did I say that? I don't see that written in my comment.

Comment: Yeah, I mean "From what you said, is also true that"